# Как создать словарь из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нам на курсе дали вот такое задание. Есть строка 'python', надо писать такой код чтобы на выходе получился словарь {1: p, 2: y.....} и так до конца. Использовать библиотеки нельзя.

Я написала вот так код

```
str1 = "Python"
dic = {}
keys = range(1, 7)
for i in range(0, len(str1)):
    for key in keys:
        dic.update({key: str[i]})
print(dic)
```

Но оно почему то не работает. Подскажите в чём проблема? Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать все куда проще :)

К отдельным буквам строки `'Python'` можно обращаться по индексам, как у списков. Например, `str1[0]` будем иметь значение первой буквы, то есть `'P'`

Таким образом, в цикле `for` от `1` до `len(str1)+1` *(чтобы нумерация в словаре шла с единицы)* заполняем словарь

Но поскольку нумерация символов `str1` начинается с `0`, в каждой итерации при обращении к отдельной букве нам нужно вычесть `1` из `i`

```
str1 = "Python"
dic = {}
for i in range(1, len(str1)+1):
    dic[i] = str1[i-1]
print(dic)
```

**Вывод:**

```
{1: 'P', 2: 'y', 3: 't', 4: 'h', 5: 'o', 6: 'n'}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Очень помогли! Не додумалась написать dic[i] = str1[i-1]. ☺

Comment: Кст, думаю, действительно лучше `range(len(str))`, а вот в ключ записывать с `+1`

Comment: Да, пожалуй так

Answer (score 5):

```
str1 = "Python"
dic = dict(enumerate(str1, start=1))
```

Comment: Очень понравился функция start. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 4):

Для присваивания индексов к элементам коллекций удобно использовать функцию `enumerate`:

```
str1 = "Python"
dic = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(str1, 1)}
print(dic)
# {1: 'P', 2: 'y', 3: 't', 4: 'h', 5: 'o', 6: 'n'}
```

Comment: В питоне походу при желании можно вообще любой код написать в одну строчку))

Comment: @denisnumb, :D В ответе `strawdog` еще проще сделано :)

Comment: Первый раз работаю с функцией enumerate. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @python_prog, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так:

```
str1 = "Python"
dic = {}

for item, value in enumerate(str1):
    # item - индекс значения из строки(счет с 0), value - символ из str1
    dic[item + 1] = value # ключ словаря - индекс + 1, значение ключа - символ строки
print(dic)
```

Вывод:

```
{1: 'P', 2: 'y', 3: 't', 4: 'h', 5: 'o', 6: 'n'}
```

Comment: У меня почему-то цикл for с двумя аргументами не работала, но наверное у меня другая ошибка была, сейчас всё работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @python_prog наверно, просто, `enumerate` пропустили.